# Summarising plenty variables using different functions

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to compute for all variables of a big data frame either the sum or the mean (or every other possible summary). This should be done if possible in only one pipe. As far as I know you can use `sumarise()` only in a way that the function for each variable is selected seperately (e.g. `summarise(., mean_var1 = mean(var1), sum_var2 = sum(var2), ...)`). This would be way to much typing. On the other hand I think `summarise_each()` can handle multiple columns but it is not possible to say that I want the mean of columns 1 and the sum of all other columns.

I'm looking for a way to combine the variability of `summarise` and the scale of `summarise_each`. Something like `summarise( name(df)[1] = mean(.[ ,1]),  name(df)[2:3] = sum(.[ ,2:3]) )`. Is this possible with `dplyr`?

Some Toy data:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(a = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE), 
                 b = rnorm(100),
                 c = rnorm (100))
```

The desired output:

```
 df %>%
  summarise(a = mean(a), b = sum(b), c = sum(c))
     a         b        c
1 0.48 -1.757949 2.277879
```

Comment: Usng `summarise_each`, it will give the sum, mean of all the columns currently `df %>% summarise_each(funs(mean, sum))`  One option would be `df %>% mutate(a= mean(a)) %>% group_by(a) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this a bit more easily in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, c(a=mean(a), lapply(.SD, sum)), .SDcols = b:c]
#     a         b        c
#1: 0.48 -1.757949 2.277879
```

---

One option with `dplyr` would be to get the `mean` of 'a' and then do the `summarise_each`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(a= mean(a)) %>%
    group_by(a) %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(sum))
#  a         b        c
#  <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#1  0.48 -1.757949 2.277879
```

Or combine with `dmap`

```
library(purrr)
dmap_at(df, "a", mean) %>%
        dmap_at(., names(.)[-1], sum) %>%
        distinct()
#     a         b        c
#1 0.48 -1.757949 2.277879
```

Comment: Is it possible to add your  data table solution to a dplyr pipe?

Comment: @Alex Isn't that a single piece of code?  You want it to be split up?

Comment: @Alex you can do `setDT(df) %>% .[, c(mean(a), lapply(.SD, sum)), .SDcols = b:c]`

Comment: I want to use it in a longer pipe where I also use `group` and some other `dplyr` functions. But I think I can work with your answer ;)